# Edit Mode in DetailView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I suppose, that I have a somewhat simple question: I have a Master/Detail application and in the the master view of this application, I have the possibilitiy to add or delete some items. Now, I want to offer a chance to edit some details of an item in the corresponding detail view. 
Usually, it's quite simple to set a view controller to edit mode and display an edit button: I just would do this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [self editButtonItem];
   //do other stuff.
}
```

and then of course, I would have to overwrite `setEditing`:

```
-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    // other editing stuff...
}
```

But as I do not have a navigation controller in my detail view, that doesn't work! I cannot access the toolbar to place a button right there, and thus I cannot reach the edit mode. What am I doing wrong here? Can I reach edit mode in a detail view at all? Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: The information in the detail view, that I would like to edit is already placed in `UITextField`s So, do I have to implement some custom logic for entering an edit mode in my detail view controller, which is NOT a `UITableViewController`? And if I have to do that: how can I access the toolbar in the detail view? Or is it better to place a custom button somewhere else on the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, meanwhile I have a solution, even if it is not really funny: Obviously, the only way to access edit mode in a view is having a table view. So I modified the whole view to be able to use a `TableViewController`. This was really a lot of work, but it works!